# fopen not creating a file when w+ is specified as mode

Tags: php, fopen

given the following running on a windows machine, I would expect a file to be created in the document root directory, but it is not.

```
$file = str_replace("\\",'/',dirname(__FILE__).'/swsql.bat');
$handle = fopen($file,'w+b'); //using binary mode for windows
fwrite($handle,'test');
fclose($handle);
```

I am following the documentation given here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and since the project I'm working on is running php version 4 I cannot use file_put_contents().  Also I have tried it without specifying binary mode and get the same result.

I've used `echo` to output the $file variable with and without the `str_replace`.  without it the string contains backslashes `\` with it the string contains forward slashes `/` according to the documentation if you don't want to escape backslashes `\\` you can use forward slashes as windows respects both.  Since `dirname(__FILE__)` returns unescaped backslashes, I'm fixing it using `str_replace`.  The contents of `$file` are exactly what I'd expect them to be, the current path of the file being interpreted appended with `/swsql.bat/`  Also there are no errors in the error log.

**EDIT**

changing `$file = str_replace("\\",'/',dirname(__FILE__).'/swsql.bat');` 
to
`$file = str_replace("\\",'/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/swsql.bat';` fixed the issue.

`

Comment: Does your script have write permission on that directory?

Comment: It should, though I'm not entirely sure how to check

Comment: Make sure `$file` holds the value you think it holds. Everything else looks fine to me although I have to confess I've never written any PHP code, only read it, so I'm no expert here.

Comment: It looks like you are using str_replace to convert your slashes in a wrong manner... Try without it and change your last slash to \\

Comment: @rfsbsb please see my last edit

Comment: What does `var_dump($handle)` show?

Comment: @rfsbsb thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
$file = str_replace("\\",'/',dirname(__FILE__).'/swsql.bat');
```

to

```
$file = str_replace("\\",'/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/swsql.bat';
```

fixed the issue.